# Hyperlink to Worksheet in actual Workbook

Tags: vba, hyperlink, worksheet, excel

How can i add a Hyperlink to a specific cell and address it to a Worksheet in the Excel file?

This is what I already got:

```
Cells(zeile, 1).Select
Worksheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=Workbooks(1).Worksheets(fortnr), SubAddress:=Cells(1, 1).Address
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, "", Sheets(fortnr).Name & "!A1"
```

The Address should be blank and the SubAddress should be in the form Sheet1!A1.  This puts a link in the activecell assuming you have a variable named fortnr that contains a valid sheet name in the same workbook.

If you want to point to a cell in a different workbook, then everything is the same except the Address needs to be that file.

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, Workbooks(1).FullName, Sheets(fortnr).Name & "!A1"
```

Assuming Workbooks(1) is a different file and has been previously saved and has a sheet with the right name, etc, etc.

Comment: ok that works, but if i open up a diffrent excel file first it will try to link the hyperlink to that file.
is it possible to always link it to the active workbook?
the name of the excel file changes itself alot, so no references on the file name.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1: Add a hyperlink to current active cell**

Assume the sheet name to link to is "VBA1"

> ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Activecell, "", "VBA1!A1"

**Idea 2: Add a hyperlink to a shape that is named as "CallButton"**

> ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveSheet.Shapes("CallButton"), "", "VBA1!A1"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this via UI:

- Go to Insert,  Hyperlink
- Select Place in This Document
- Select the worksheets and the cells you want to add.

The links will be added in your spreasheet.

[image]