# Excel VBA Creating a Hyperlink in a different worksheet to a different worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am working on a project in Excel where I want to validate a data set, whenever two cells in a column have a duplicate I want to write the location of the duplicate to a different worksheet that contains a bunch of information regarding errors in the data.

So my data is in worksheet1 and when I run my code I am writing a hyperlink to some cell in worksheet2 that links to the error in worksheet1.

I found some code which almost accomplishes this task in a different stack question...

[Hyperlink to Existing Worksheet in actual Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820191/hyperlink-to-existing-worksheet-in-actual-workbook)

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, "", Sheets(fortnr).Name & "!A1"
```

However this creates a hyper link in the workbook you are currently in (or is active).

I modified the code a bit, but can't seem to get it to run...

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Hyperlinks.Add Cells(3, 3), "", Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!B2", _
"", "Hello"
```

I have also tried

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(3, 3), "", Sheets(fortnr).Name & "!A1"
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

But it doesn't work. There is no error produced either so I am really at a loss as to why this isn't working.

Comment: @PortlandRunner Yes, when I run the code while being in Sheet 1, the C3 in sheet 1 gets the cell that says "Hello", C3 in sheet 3 is empty. I pasted the code into a brand new workbook as well so there is no chance the sheets are named anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your anchor cell isn't specifying the sheet to anchor to so it defaults to the active sheet.

Change it like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, 3), "", Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!B2", "", "Hello"
```

---

Why do you need to have a sheet before `.Hyperlinks`?

Based on the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx) I believe it's because `HyperLinks` is a method of the `sheets` class so it's the only way to invoke the method.  You can use `Activesheet` or call any sheet at the start to invoke the method then assign the hyperlink anchor to your desired location.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. But then why do we even have a Sheets("Sheet3") before the Hyperlinks.Add? I thought that was where the anchor was being specified.

Answer (score 0):

These are the ones I use to create hyperlinks on VBA to a URL or a specific spreadsheet

```
Sheets("RogueOne").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("RogueOne").Cells(3, 4), Address:="http://wired.com", ScreenTip:="Wired", TextToDisplay:="WIRED"
    Sheets("RogueOne").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("RogueOne").Cells(5, 5), "", Sheets("RogueTwo").Name & "!c2", "", "RogueTwo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this...

```
Dim WS as Worksheet
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & WS.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=WS.Name
```

Because when you look at the link, it usually shows

```
file:///name'WS.name'!A1
```

and it could be possible that the pair of ' '  may have been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I experienced "Hyperlink is not valid" error when I clicked to hyperlink created by Portlands Runner code. Surrounding and joining **Sheets("Sheet1").Name** by aphostrophes resolved that problem and that error was gone. If you experience the same, then use it like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, 3), "", "'" & Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "'" & "!B2", "", "Hello"
```